# How to replace Array in Hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following HashMap:

```
["Hello": ([342342342332, 20], [3230239323, 21])]
```

...which I created like this...

```
Map<String, List<long[]>> interestingMap = new HashMap<>();
interestingMap.put("Hello", new ArrayList<>());
interestingMap.get("Hello").add({342342342332L, 20L});
interestingMap.get("Hello").add({3230239323L, 21L});
```

I would like to change the second value in the ArrayList in "interestingMap" depending on the first value of the ArrayList. So if the first value is = "342342342332", I'd like to update the second value from "20" to "30".

This is what I have so far:

```
for (long[] interestingValue : interestingMap.get("Hello")) {
   if (interestingValue[0] == 342342342332) {
      interestingMap.get("Hello").set(interestingValue[0],30);
   }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: (`ArrayList<>` != `long[][]`)

Comment: java: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for java.util.ArrayList<>
    reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that java.util.ArrayList<E> conforms to long[][]

Comment: made a mistake - it's updated now

Comment: "`add({342342342332L, 20L})`" no, you didn't do this. You can only use this short syntax in an assignment context.

Comment: "`interestingMap.get("Hello").set(interestingValue[0],30);`" So, you're setting the 342342342332th element of a list to 30? I'm going to guess your list isn't that long really.

Comment: It looks like you need a POJO here, instead of this ambiguous type `long[]`. Any ways, the solution is to replace: `interestingMap.get("Hello").set(interestingValue[0],30);` with `interestingValue[1] = 30;`

Comment: If you want to do this sort of operations, why not have `Map<String, Map<Long, Long>>`?

Comment: Post your real code that you used - don't post fake code that doesn't compile. The `put` call, both the `add` calls, the `if (interestingValue[0] == 342342342332)` and the `set` call don't compile. Actually, there are only two lines with letters on it that do compile.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you should have:

```
for (long[] interestingValue : interestingMap.get("Hello")) {
    if (interestingValue[0] == 342342342332L) {
        interestingValue[1] = 30L;
    }
}
```

This:

```
interestingMap.get("Hello").set(interestingValue[0],30);
```

Will take the element in the list at the index "interestingValue[0]" which is "342342342332" and probably doesn't exists and replace it entirely with "30" which I'm surprised if it even compile because it is just an integer and the list take arrays of long.

I don't know why you have an array inside a list inside a map, you could have a totally acceptable reason but one possibility is that you don't create the objects that you should and rely to much on existing Java objects, so maybe take a time to think if you could make it better by creating some objects.

Also read the APIs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void changeInteresting(){
        Map<String, List<long[]>> interestingMap = new HashMap<>();
        interestingMap.put("Hello", new ArrayList<>());
        long [] first=new long[]{342342342332L, 20L};
        long [] second=new long[]{3230239323L, 21L};
        interestingMap.get("Hello").add(first);
        interestingMap.get("Hello").add(second);
        int index=0;
        for (long[] interestingValue : interestingMap.get("Hello")) {
               if (interestingValue[0] == 342342342332L) {
                   interestingValue[1]=30L;
                   interestingMap.get("Hello").set(index, interestingValue);
               }
               index++;
            }


        System.out.println(interestingMap);
    }
```

Please find ans to your queries.  I have modified a bit accordingly working properly.